# Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN even when using the domain that is mentioned in the error message

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I go on the website:
http://darienpilates.com/
or
https://darienpilates.com/

I get:

> 192.34.57.38 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: www.darienpilates.com,
>   darienpilates.com Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

well, I did user **darienpilates.com**, so it should work. The error seems to remove its own credibility.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\>curl -v http://darienpilates.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://darienpilates.com/
*   Trying 184.168.221.5...
* Connected to darienpilates.com (184.168.221.5) port 80 (#0)

...

<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="https://192.34.57.38/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 06 -->
<!-- -->
</html>* Connection #0 to host darienpilates.com left intact
```

So your page is trying to insert iframe form https://192.34.57.38/, and you get an error since that site has SSL certificate valid only for www.darienpilates.com (which you can confirm by simply opening https://192.34.57.38/ in your browser.

And https://darienpilates.com/ is not responding at all:

```
C:\>curl -v https://darienpilates.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://darienpilates.com/
*   Trying 184.168.221.5...
* connect to 184.168.221.5 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to darienpilates.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to darienpilates.com port 443: Connection refused
```